# How can I detect a Windows Store HTML5/Javascript app's version at runtime?

Tags: windows-store-apps

The version number of a Windows Store HTML5/Javascript app is specified in the file `package.appxmanifest`.  How can I read the version within my app at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version number can be accessed via `Windows.ApplicationModel.Package`:

```
var ver = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.current.id.version
var versionStr = ver.major + '.' + ver.minor + '.' + ver.build + ver.revision
```